# How can I debug a single ruby script in netbeans?

Tags: ruby, debugging, netbeans

All of this is on a windows xp box:

Netbeans managed to accept an existing rails project and allowed me to debug it just fine, but my project has a number of processing scripts that handle non-MVC aspects.  The rails project is just a system for queuing requests for the execution of these scripts.

I've attempted to create netbeans projects using existing sources, but it fails for a number of reasons.

First, since I have a number of scripts in one place, netbeans complains that I can't add a source directory to the project because it already belongs to another project.  If I put the script into its own, empty, directory and try to add that directory, netbeans stalls while trying to create the project and I have to end the process from the task manager.

If I create a new project for it, remove the default main.rb and replace it with the script I want to debug, the debug session will not start - netbeans complains that it cannnot find the program entry point.

It seems to me that if I can debug rails apps as easily as netbeans allows me to, that running a single standalone script would be trivial.  What on earth am I missing?

UPDATE: Loading the script and doing "Debug/Debug File" isn't possible.  The option is always greyed out, even for hello world.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project, click Properties, choose Run, and change the Main Script to your script.

You can also debug a single file in Rails project by opening the file, then click Debug in menu toolbar, then Debug "file_name.rb". Or just press Ctrl-Shift-F5 on the opened file.

Comment: The option to debug a single file is greyed out for me.  See the update on the original question.

Comment: I'm clueless. Probably you should ask at NetBeans mailing list. There is one specialized in Ruby. http://www.netbeans.org/community/lists/top.html